# I cannot set value in a Holder<Integer> with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am making unit tests for a service in my application. Inside this service there is a call to an external webservice (`SOAP`). The call to this webservice set values to different `Holder<String>` and `Holder<Integer>` I have send as parameter to this WS call.

This is my Service method:

**CustomerServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public Customer createCustomer(Customer dto) {

    UserEkos userEkos = SecurityEkosUtils.getUserEkos();

    if (dto.getOrigen() != null && dto.getOrigen().equalsIgnoreCase(DEL)) {

        Optional<CustomerModel> result = customerRepository.findById(dto.getId());
        if (!result.isPresent()) {
            log.error("[createCustomer] The central does exist in SAP " + dto.getId());
            throw new BusinessServiceException(Constants.FUNCTIONAL_ERROR, " The central does exist in SAP " + dto.getId());
        }
    } else if(dto.getOrigen() != null && !dto.getOrigen().equalsIgnoreCase(DEL)) {
        log.error("[createCustomer] Do not introduce an ID");
        throw new BusinessServiceException(Constants.FUNCTIONAL_ERROR, "Do not introduce an ID");
    }

    Zwcta293 zwcta293 = altaDeudoresMapper.dtoToZwcta293(dto);

    Holder<String> eCodCreated = new Holder<>();
    Holder<String> eMessage = new Holder<>();
    Holder<Integer> eReturn = new Holder<>();
    Holder<String> eSocCreated = new Holder<>();
    Holder<String> eResidenceType = new Holder<>();

    altaProxy.zwebserAltaDeudores(zwcta293, eCodCreated, eMessage, eReturn, eSocCreated, eResidenceType);

    if (eReturn.value == 0) {
        CustomerModel customerModel = CustomerMapper.dtoToDomain(dto);

        customerModel.setId(eCodCreated.value);

        if (dto.getSocieties() != null && !dto.getSocieties().isEmpty()) {
            CustomerSocietyModel customerSociety = new CustomerSocietyModel();
            customerSociety.setCustomer(customerModel.getId());
            customerSociety.setSociety(userEkos.getSociety());
            customerModel.addCustomerSociety(customerSociety);
        }

        customerRepository.save(customerModel);
    } else {
        log.error("[createCustomer] Error SAP " + eMessage.value);
        throw new BusinessServiceException(Constants.FUNCTIONAL_ERROR, "Error SAP " + eMessage.value);
    }

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId(eCodCreated.value);
    return customer;
}
```

This is my test method:

**CustomerServiceTest**

```
@Test
void createCustomerOKTest() throws Exception{

    Holder<String> eCodCreated = new Holder<>();
    Holder<String> eMessage = new Holder<>();
    Holder<Integer> eReturn = new Holder<>();
    Holder<String> eSocCreated = new Holder<>();
    Holder<String> eResidenceType = new Holder<>();


    Customer customer = (Customer) UtilsTest.getFileJsonToFile(CUSTOMER_JSON, Customer.class);
    customer.setId("1239000");
    Zwcta293 sapCustomer = (Zwcta293) UtilsTest.getFileJsonToFile(CUSTOMER_SAP_JSON, Zwcta293.class);
    CustomerModel customerModel = (CustomerModel) UtilsTest.getFileJsonToFile(CUSTOMER_MODEL, CustomerModel.class);

    when(altaDeudoresMapper.dtoToZwcta293(any(Customer.class))).thenReturn(sapCustomer);

    doAnswer(invoication -> {
                Holder<String> eCodCreated1 = (Holder<String>) invoication.getArgument(1);
                Holder<String> eMessage1 = (Holder<String>) invoication.getArgument(2);
                Holder<Integer> eReturn1 = (Holder<Integer>) invoication.getArgument(3);
                Holder<String> eSocCreated1 = (Holder<String>) invoication.getArgument(4);
                Holder<String> eResidenceType1 = (Holder<String>) invoication.getArgument(5);

                eReturn1.value = 1239000;
                return null;
            }).when(altaProxy).zwebserAltaDeudores(sapCustomer, eCodCreated, eMessage, eReturn, eSocCreated, eResidenceType);
    when(customerRepository.save(Mockito.any(CustomerModel.class))).thenReturn(customerModel);

    Customer customerFinal = customerService.createCustomer(customer);

    assertSame(Integer.toString(1239000), customerFinal.getId());
}
```

When it reaches the line in the service `if(eRetorno.value == 0)` I get a `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.vocento.ekos.customer.service.CustomerServiceImpl.createCustomer(CustomerServiceImpl.java:83)
at com.vocento.ekos.customer.service.CustomerServiceTest.createCustomerOKTest(CustomerServiceTest.java:131)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I know why it returns `NullPointerException` but my problem is that I do not really know how to make it work. My service uses the Holder values inside the method to proceed further or not but I do not know any way to get this Holder value in my test or any way to mock them.

I tried to set a value to the Holders I am passing as a parameter in the Unit Test but it did not work either. Also, I tried to mock the Holder to send them as parameters rather than passing a real object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by changing my `doAnswer().when()` code to this:

```
 doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
        Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
        if(arguments != null && arguments.length > 1 && arguments[0] != null && arguments[1] != null){
            Holder<String> eCodCreated = (Holder<String>) arguments[1];
            Holder<Integer> eReturn = (Holder<Integer>) arguments[3];
            Holder<String> eSocCreated = (Holder<String>) arguments[4];
            eReturn.value = 0;
            eCodCreated.value = "1239000";
            eSocCreated.value = "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    ).when(altaProxy).zwebserAltaDeudores(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

I had to add another line of code after setting the ´Holder´ value I wanted so that it could set properly.